# What fiscal scrutiny can be expected from IRS in early retirement?

Tags: united-states, retirement, irs

From [Tim Ferriss](http://fourhourworkweek.com/blog/) to [Mr. Money Mustache](http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/), fueled by contemporary prospects of making riches in technology and real estate, to name a few, one of the most popular subjects in the personal finance blogosphere is early retirement and financial independence.

Assuming that a person of a non-conventional retirement age, say 35 or 40, were to withdraw from workforce resting on their savings alone, meaning no income, including social entitlements (unemployment or welfare), what kind of fiscal scrutiny can that person expect in the U.S. from IRS ?  If one were to live entirely off their savings, not even having investment income, are they obligated to file their tax return?  Basically, is 1040 required in the U.S. even if no income was generated and does that raise any red flags to IRS auditors when a young person reports no income but also no withdrawals from any retirement account because they are not of age yet?

Comment: From personal experience, no.  There have been several years of my life in which I did not earn enough to make it necessary to file, so I didn't, and never had any sort of inquiry from the IRS.  Though note they were isolated years (for finishing thesis, travel, etc), not a stretch of several continuous years.  And of course many people do similar withdrawals from work due to marriage, children, etc.

Comment: How can one have enough to retire but not enough interest or dividends to need to file?

Comment: by having cash in a checking account, @JoeTaxpayer

Comment: @amphibient $35k/year for 40 years, so $1.4M, absolute minimum I'd guess.  Someone's going to put that in a zero-interest checking account, and not even try to get a percent of interest or two from insured CDs?  I have to say I doubt that.  Not to mention inflationary concerns, who knows how much you'd have to have.  Unless you're talking entirely off the grid...

Comment: it could be a temporary retirement, AKA sabbatical

Comment: 40 years of inflation, $35,000 will feel like $12,000 or so. You'd need $100.000 to have same spending power. You're asking for a combination that's tough to manage. But yes, you can retire and spend your life under the filing requirement. If that's your goal.

Comment: Please note this is not intended to be a discussion on feasibility. The question is clearly stated

Comment: Fair enough. Seems you have your answer below.

Comment: @Joe: People do stranger things than keep money in zero-interest checking accounts.  Couple of years ago there was a local guy who died, and the people clearing out his house found about $7 million in gold: http://www.kolotv.com/home/headlines/7-Million-in-Gold-Coins-Found-after-Mans-Death--170278836.html

Comment: @Joe - Funny his question, long as it is, reduces to one of filing requirement. It's hypothetical, and results in a scenario that no on would recommend. An eccentric dot com (or high tech these days) millionaire can cash out, put $millions in the safe, and no longer file after declaring that sale. (Obama care aside)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer And I suppose someone with zero income doesn't have to show insured status and/or pay the penalty, even if they've got millions in cash...

Comment: Regarding ACA - [What are the statutory exemptions from the requirement to obtain minimum essential coverage?](http://www.irs.gov/Affordable-Care-Act/Individuals-and-Families/Questions-and-Answers-on-the-Individual-Shared-Responsibility-Provision)  - "Your income is below the minimum threshold for filing a tax return. The requirement to file a federal tax return depends on your filing status, age and types and amounts of income." See Sec 6 para4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IRS Pub 554](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p554/ch01.html) states (click to read full IRS doc):

[image]

"Do not file a federal income tax return if you do not meet the filing requirements and are not due a refund.
...
If you are a U.S. citizen or resident alien, you must file a return if your gross income for the year was at least the amount shown on the appropriate line in Table 1-1 below. "

You may not have wage income, but you will probably have interest, dividend, capital gains, or proceeds from sale of a house (and there is a special note that you must file in this case, even if you enjoy the exclusion for primary residence)

Comment: What role does the Affordable Care Act play in the filing rules? Isn't proof of coverage via tax documents?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep if your income is below the filing requirement then your penalty will probably be zero anyway.

Comment: But do you have to file?

Comment: Note that the statute of limitations does not begin until a return is filed.

Comment: see my comment above regarding ACA